# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink

i develop an application with swing

i habe a database with few tables; these Tables are connected with foreign key
 When I try to run this application , i have the error;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: Bezeichner ist zu lang

Error Code: 972
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:117)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:92)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getKinokindergeldfallFindAll(Unknown Source)
    at de.itech.kiwi.startseite.actionPerformed(startseite.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: Bezeichner ist zu lang

Error Code: 972
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2769)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2722)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2977)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1589)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2051)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1589)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1554)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:411)
    at weblogic.persistence.QueryProxyImpl.getResultList(QueryProxyImpl.java:145)
    at de.itech.kino.model.ItechSessionEJBBean.getKinokindergeldfallFindAll(ItechSessionEJBBean.java:167)
    at de.itech.kino.model.ItechSessionEJB_ohevbk_ItechSessionEJBImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at de.itech.kino.model.ItechSessionEJB_ohevbk_ItechSessionEJBImpl.getKinokindergeldfallFindAll(Unknown Source)
    at de.itech.kino.model.ItechSessionEJB_ohevbk_ItechSessionEJBImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:693)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:519)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:515)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

This table Kinokindergeldfall hat a  foreign key in the table kinoantragsteller

```
@OneToOne (cascade =  CascadeType.ALL , fetch= FetchType.EAGER)

private Kinokindergeldfall kinokindergeldfall;
```

et the class kinokindergeldfall:

```
@Column(nullable= false )
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Kinokindergeldfall_Id_Seq_Gen")
private BigDecimal kindergeldfallid;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String kindergeldnummer;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "kinokindergeldfall",   cascade =  CascadeType.ALL )
private Kinoantragsteller kinoantragstellerList;
```

Comment: Some schema object name (table, column, sequence, constraint) is too long. Oracle only allows 30 characters or so. Unfortunately, the error does not tell us the offending name. Can you get the SQL that fails?

Comment: no all the object names are to short   i think the  problem is in @oneToOne but i dont khow how  can i the problem resolve

Comment: errm, look in the log at the actual SQL?

Comment: i should change @Column(nullable= false ) to  @Column(insertable= false, updatable= false )  what is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't supply `@JoinColumn` with a column name for some relation, JPA will assume the default one. The default one is constructed like `<source_class_field_name>_<target_class_id_field_name>` which in your case resolves to `kinokindergeldfall_kindergeldfallid` which is over 30 characters long. That's what causes the exception.

Since you wouldn't be able to create a column with this name in the first place, just add `@JoinColumn(name = "<column name>")` with the actual name of the column used as foreign key to another table (shorter than 30 characters).

```
@OneToOne (cascade =  CascadeType.ALL , fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "<column name>")
private Kinokindergeldfall kinokindergeldfall;
```

Comment: now  i have another error  ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."KINOANTRAGSTELLER"."KINOKINDERGELDFALLID")  

kinokindergeldfall is a BigDecimal     plz help??

Comment: You're welcome. You should post a new question in a separate thread with all relevant code and details.

Comment: One would think that the default name takes the limitations of the database into consideration. :-(

Comment: @Thilo Yes, I agree, but it could interfere with convention-over-configuration approach.

Comment: @PredragMaric Man you are a life saver. I was stuck with a exact issue and kind of clueless and your solution worked like a mint. Thanks again :)